# enable update manager module in drupal 8

Tags: module, drupal-8

my drupal8 is missing install new theme button, I looked in the internet that it requires to enable  update manager module in drupal 8. How do I do it , Im new to drupal8 development. please help

Answer (score 0):

go to your www.yoursite.com/admin/modules

then scroll down to Update Manager and then enable it